# how to include a namespace in MVC view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am trying to include`<% @using System.Web.Script.Serialization%>` but it is giving me error message: The server block is not well formed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using Razor syntax, it's like this:

```
@using System.Web.Script.Serialization
```

ASP.net syntax is like this:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Script.Serialization" %>
```